# First Order Condition with 1 decision variable and 2D state space

Tags: optimization, reference-request, dynamic-programming, envelope

TL;DR: I'm trying to find the first-order condition (FOC) for an optimization problem with two state variables and one control variable. I don't want the value function $V$ to appear in the FOC but can't get rid of it. Help is highly appreciated.
$\def\d{\delta} \def\b{\beta} \def\g{\gamma} \def\G{\Gamma}$

A decision-maker needs to choose $a$ in every stage, payoffs are given according to a function $w$ that depends on $a$ and on the state, which is a vector with two elements $s_1,s_2$. Only the first if directly payoff relevant, but they both affect some nice function $b$ which determines the state tomorrow. Payoffs are discounted, time is discrete. The goal is to find the first-order condition in terms of all these parameters to make optimal choices.

Here is a formal statement of the problem and the calculation up until the moment where I'm stuck.

Let $s^t=\begin{pmatrix}
s^t_1 \\ s^t_2
\end{pmatrix}$ be the state vector at time $t$, $b:\mathbf{R}^2\to \mathbf{R}$ a known "nice" function, $\b, \d \in (0,1)$ constants.
$w(a^t,s^t_1)$ is the single stage payoff that depends on the action $a^t$ and the first element of the state.
The states evolve according to $s^{t+1}=\begin{pmatrix}
s^{t+1}_1 \\ s^{t+1}_2
\end{pmatrix}=\d \begin{pmatrix}
s^t_1 \\ s^t_2
\end{pmatrix}+\G \begin{pmatrix}
a^t \\ b(s^t)
\end{pmatrix}$ where
$$
\Gamma=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\gamma_{11} & \gamma_{12}\\ 
\gamma_{21} & \gamma_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

The optimization problem is therefore
$$V\begin{pmatrix}
s_1 \\ s_2\end{pmatrix}=\max\limits_{a\in[0,1]} \left[(1-\beta)w(a,s_1)+\beta V\begin{pmatrix}
\d s_1+ \g_{11} a + \g_{12}b(s) \\ \d s_2+ \g_{21} a + \g_{22} b(s)
\end{pmatrix}\right]$$

Denote the $[\ldots]$ by $L^t$ (the Lagrangian at time $t$).
The First-order condition is $\tfrac{\partial L^t}{\partial a^t}=0$:
\begin{equation}\label{foct}
    (1-\b)w_1(a^{t},s_1^t)+\b \left[\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+1}}\g_{11}+\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+1}}\g_{21} \right]=0
\end{equation}
and the similar expression at time $t+1$ is:
\begin{equation}\label{foct+1}
    (1-\b)w_1(a^{t+1},s_1^{t+1})+\b \left[\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+2}}\g_{11}+\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+2}}\g_{21} \right]=0
\end{equation}
According to the envelope theorem:
\begin{eqnarray}\label{envt}
    \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^t}&=&(1-\b) w_2(a^t,s_1^t) + \b \left[\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+1}}(\d+\g_{12}b_1(s^t))+\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+1}}\g_{22}b_1(s^t) \right] \\
      \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^t}&=&\b \left[\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+1}}\g_{12}b_2(s^t)+\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+1}}(\d+\g_{22}b_2(s^t)) \right] 
\end{eqnarray}
and for time $t+1$:
\begin{eqnarray}\label{envt+1}
    \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+1}}&=&(1-\b) w_2(a^{t+1},s_1^{t+1}) + \b \left[\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+2}}(\d+\g_{12}b_1(s^{t+1}))+\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+2}}\g_{22}b_1(s^{t+1}) \right] \\
      \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+1}}&=&\b \left[\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+2}}\g_{12}b_2(s^{t+1})+\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+2}}(\d+\g_{22}b_2(s^{t+1})) \right] 
\end{eqnarray}

We can sum these two equations to obtain
\begin{eqnarray}
    \gamma_{11}\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+1}}+\gamma_{21}\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+1}}&=&
    (1-\b) w_2(a^{t+1},s_1^{t+1})\gamma_{11} \nonumber \\
    &+&\b\gamma_{11} \left[\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+2}}(\d+\g_{12}b_1(s^{t+1}))+\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+2}}\g_{22}b_1(s^{t+1}) \right] \nonumber \\
    &+&\b\gamma_{21} \left[\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+2}}\g_{12}b_2(s^{t+1})+\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+2}}(\d+\g_{22}b_2(s^{t+1})) \right] \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}
The $\delta$ part of this is
$$\beta\delta \left[\gamma_{11}\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+2}}+\gamma_{21}\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+2}} \right]=-\delta (1-\beta) w_1(a^{t+1},s_1^{t+1})$$
The rest is
\begin{eqnarray}
\b\left[\gamma_{11}b_1(s^{t+1})+\gamma_{21}b_2(s^{t+1}) \right]\left[\gamma_{12}\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+2}}+ \gamma_{22} \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+2}}\right]
\end{eqnarray}
Hence the FOC has the following form (also divide by $1-\b$):
\begin{eqnarray}\label{foct_neet}
w_1(a^{t},s_1^t)+\b \left[w_2(a^{t+1},s_1^{t+1})\gamma_{11} -\delta w_1(a^{t+1},s_1^{t+1})\right]\nonumber \\
+\tfrac{\b}{1-\b}\left[\gamma_{11}b_1(s^{t+1})+\gamma_{21}b_2(s^{t+1}) \right]\left[\gamma_{12}\tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_1^{t+2}}+ \gamma_{22} \tfrac{\partial V}{\partial s_2^{t+2}}\right]=0
\end{eqnarray}
Where the first line is fine but the second line is the problematic one. How one can get rid of $V$ from this equation? Any conditions or equations that I can write that I'm missing?

(Any references about this kind of problems are also welcome)

Added in edit: I have here 6 linear equations in 6 variables so in theory I can solve it and finish with it. However, I want to generalize it to $n$-dimensional state space, and such approach won't work there.

Comment: I don't see how you get rid of the objective function. If you could do that, it would mean that any optimal solution would be independent of the objective. It seems quite weird.

Comment: Not exactly, as $V$ is determined by $w$ and the optimal solution. For example, if $b$ is a constant function then $b_1=b_2=0$, the second line drops and you have a nice FOC without $V$.